# undefined method for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been maintaining this system for almost 3 years now and the system is using rails 1.2.6
I have a problem when adding new attributes to the model.  I get an undefined method for model error.

This worked previously but this time i could not fix it, even though when i run it in console, it is ok.

I have created 3 models with has_many :through relationship.  I don't understand migrations well, so I have always created the tables manually.

```
class Casedf < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :casespus
 has_many :spucats, :through => :casespus
end

class Spucat < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :casedfs, :through => :casespus
 has_many :casespus
end

class Casespu < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :casedf
 belongs_to :spucat
end
```

my new.rhtml

```
 <td>Category<img src="/main/images/asterick1.gif" height="10" width="10" alt=""></td>
<td>:</td>
<td><select name="case[spucats][]" multiple>
         <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
             <% @spus.each do |category|%>
         <option value="<%= category.id%>">
             <%= category.name%> </option>
         <%end%>
    </select>
</td>
```

when i tried to create new Casedf, I get this error:

```
Undefined method 'spucats=' for #<Casedf:....>
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-1.15.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1860:in `method_missing'       
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-1.15.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1675:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-1.15.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1675:in `attributes='
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-1.15.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1674:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-1.15.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1674:in `attributes='
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-1.15.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1508:in `initialize_without_callbacks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-1.15.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:225:in `initialize'
/home/jaz/dfp/app/controllers/casedf_controller.rb:89:in `new'
/home/jaz/dfp/app/controllers/casedf_controller.rb:89:in `createcase'
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Please help point something out. I've been looking at this for weeks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in rails, your models need to subclass from ActiveRecord.   I hope you have made a typo in pasting. because you hav an extra space in your has_many calls

Comment: I assume he's just mistyped the models here, since he'd be hitting method errors at load time on the validations if he hasn't.  My bet is on "manual table creation" being the problem...

Comment: yes true, a lot of incomplete code and typos.sorry.will correct 'em

Comment: marc: manual table creation?  but when i do script/console, the casedf created just fine. i did manually for others as well.but they all turned out fine.please explain.TQ.

Comment: casespu belongs to spucat , not spucats - I think rails pluralization is biting you

Comment: unrelated, maybe, but what are casedf's or casespu?  Is that another language, or have you shortened something to an acronym like name?  The Rails way is to use longer, word-like names.  That often helps eliminate errors with pluralization, because it is more natural (in English anyway) to say "has many cases" than "has many case" or "Belongs to (a) case" vs "belongs to (a) cases". The second example of each pair sounds obviously wrong, at least to native English speakers. :)

Comment: DGM: sorry another typos. it is actually spucat.

Comment: DGM:yeah i named it that way ( my language way) so that i can differentiate them better.So lemme try and change the names.

Comment: but what is it? SpudCategory?   A longer name is usually preferred in rails

Comment: DGM: yes, its a category belongs to a team called SPU